# how to access Hadoop -D argument

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This is the command:

```
hadoop jar PopularityLeague.jar PopularityLeague -D league=dataset/league.txt
```

How can I access the '**league=dataset/league.txt**' inside of the Hadoop Java?

I searched this problem, and some one just says I might use configuration to do it. I don't know how exactly I can do it.

Comment: This doesn't upload a file, by the way, just provides a key value pair, which you could just as easily do with arguments instead of system property -D... What is your goal? Can you please show your Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am only answering how you can use -D option
To change replication factor below command will be used while storing data to HDFS using -D.

```
hdfs dfs -Ddfs.replication=1 -put /data/dpq/dummy/temp/GDGA111_1_20180918111340752.csv /data/dpq/temp
```

Can you try something around similar lines ?

Comment: Do you know how to access "league=dataset/league.txt" inside a java file? Since I need to  use "dataset/league.txt" inside of java fil.e

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use "dataset/league.txt" inside of java file

If you look at some example mapreduce programs, they might have `new Path(args[0])` inside the main method

That command invocation would look like this, not using system properties

```
hadoop jar PopularityLeague.jar PopularityLeague dataset/league.txt
```